# iOS NSNotification Simple Xcode Project Problems

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm now learning notification programming, have a very simple project have two classes that have a little problems that dont't call notification selector method when posting notification. That's very weird, hope someone help me find where problems occurred, i'm very appreciated that!

My source code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *pushButton;

- (IBAction)presentViewController:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)presentViewController:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"networkNotification"
                                                        object:self];
    ViewController2 *viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController2
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}

@end
```

ViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

ViewController2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

@synthesize testLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(recievingNotifications:)
                                                 name:@"networkNotification"
                                               object:self.viewController];
}

- (void)recievingNotifications:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if ([[aNotification name] isEqualToString:@"networkNotification"])
    {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        self.testLabel.text = @"Good";
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"networkNotification"
                                                  object:self.viewController];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you passing self as the object, seems like nil would do fine here on both sender and receiver

Comment: Are you sure `presentViewController` is even being called?

Comment: @DCS123 Because i passed the ViewController instance as notification sender previously.

Comment: @AaronGolden No, is not called, so this is the problem occurred, i don't know what's wrong? Can you help me find what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. You post the notification before anyone is registered to receive it.
2. When adding the observer you filter to an instance that doesn't post a notification (`object:self.viewController`).

For 1. Notifications aren't stored, they are received only by observers attached when the notification is posted.

For 2. Notifications can be posted with an object and observers can filter on that object. If the objects don't match the method won't be called. Set the object to nil when observing if you don't want any filtering done.

Swap the order of your view controller presentation and the notification posting:

```
ViewController2 *viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];

    [self presentViewController:viewController2
                   animated:YES
                   completion:^{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"networkNotification"
                                                    object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Even though OP might not need the filtering, it looks to me like he's actually using the same object in both cases so that isn't the thing keeping the notification from going through.  The problem (from OP's latest comment) is that the method that posts the notification is never called at all.

Comment: There's a circularity between the two controllers so its hard to tell whether the objects are the same. I guess not.

Comment: ah, you're right, ok.  I bet OP doesn't mean to be creating a whole new view controller in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I can understand set the sender object to nil, but why are you say post the notification before anyone is registered to receive it? Sorry, i don't understand it. What should i do for modify it?

Comment: Thanks! I have know the principles that why you made swop of the call order between the presenting viewController and posting notifications.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues I found on your code

**1)**

```
- (IBAction)presentViewController:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"networkNotification"
                                                        object:self];
    ViewController2 *viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController2
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Here you are posting a notification then displays the `ViewController2`, here you sent the notification but there is no receiver available at the current point of time. So nothing will happen.

Check with:

```
- (IBAction)presentViewController:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController2
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"networkNotification"
                                                        object:self];
}
```

**2)**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(recievingNotifications:)
                                                 name:@"networkNotification"
                                               object:self.viewController];
}
```

Why are you again allocating `ViewController` ?

Just pass it from the `presentViewController:` method.

Comment: Thanks! I understand your means, but what should i do for post the notification after anyone is registered to receive it on this project?

Comment: @Andy_24: I didn't understand your comment. Anyway there is no way to check whether there is a listener available or not. For this situation I added a suggestion above. Please check that, I' not sure whether it'll work or not